# How to remove only top node from Expression tree?

Tags: c#, .net

my task is to modify an `Expression` according to several rules. One of them is to remove top level convert expression if there is such, but only top, not inner. I've implemented flowing class

```cs
class RemoveConvertToObjectExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
    {
        if (node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert || node.NodeType == ExpressionType.ConvertChecked)
        {
            return base.Visit(node.Operand);
        }
        return base.VisitUnary(node);
    }
}
```

but it removes ALL convert expressions. See the example below (it is just a sample of a behavior, no much sense in the code itself).

```cs
class Model
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    Expression<Func<Model, object>> expression = m => m.Value + int.Parse( ( (object) "5").ToString() );

    var visitor = new RemoveConvertToObjectExpressionVisitor();

    var result = visitor.Visit(expression.Body);
}
```

I want the result expression to be `m.Value +  Parse(Convert("5").ToString())`, but it gives `m.Value + Parse("5".ToString())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code removes all conversion expressions is that the code of the visitor has no idea if it is looking at the top level or not. All it knows is that it's a conversion expression.

Changing this through an `ExpressionVisitor` implementation is tricky, because you need to tell from inside the visitor if you are looking at the root expression or not. One way of doing it is defining a `bool` variable `topLevel`, setting it to `true` at the beginning, and then setting it to `false` inside all your `VisitXYZ` methods:

```
class RemoveConvertToObjectExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
    private bool topLevel = true;
    protected override Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node) {
        bool currentTop = topLevel;
        topLevel = false;
        if (currentTop && (node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert || node.NodeType == ExpressionType.ConvertChecked)) {
            return base.Visit(node.Operand);
        }
        return base.VisitUnary(node);
    }
    /// You need to override all VisitXyz methods with the same code
    protected override Visit...(...Expression node) {
        topLevel = false;
        return base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

This requires a lot of code, and even more effort from the reader to understand what is happening. You would be much better off with a simple type check on the top-level expression, and grabbing its operand if you see a conversion:

```
Expression<Func<Model, object>> expression = m => m.Value + int.Parse( ( (object) "5").ToString() );

Expression result = expression.Body;    
bool isConvertTopNode = result.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert || result.NodeType == ExpressionType.ConvertChecked;   
if (isConvertTopNode) 
{
    result = ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand;
}
```

Comment: The second suggestion seems to be a good one, but it does not compile - gives `Cannot convert type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<UserQuery.Model,object>>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression'`

Comment: @PavelK The changed answer should work better. It's using your visitor. However, it assumes that you always start with a top-level lambda expression.

Comment: Now when I tried for my example `var v = new RemoveConvertToObjectExpressionVisitor(); v.Visit(expression);` I've got `ArgumentException` `Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'`.

Comment: But when I've changed the method you've removed and changed it a little bit it seems to work
 `if (expression.Body .NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert || expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.ConvertChecked) {
     ((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand.Dump();
 }`

Comment: @PavelK You get an exception because you have removed the cast.

Comment: Maybe you could add this method to the answer and I would accept it because that worked for me

Comment: @PavelK I am not sure where does the added code go. You can suggest an edit by clicking [edit] above, and I'll promptly approve it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47876/discussion-between-pavel-k-and-dasblinkenlight)